# Date column returning number if NA is precent

Tags: r

I am trying to incorporate date in a column. But it is returning number since NA is present. Can anyone help me?

```
asdd <- data.frame(a = c(NA,as.Date(today(),"%m/%d/%Y")), b = c(2,3))
asdd
      a b
1    NA 2
2 19220 3
```

i want get as Date in the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `as.Date` before `c` and not inside `c`.

```
data.frame(a = as.Date(c(NA, "1970-01-01")), b = c(2,3))
#           a b
#1       <NA> 2
#2 1970-01-01 3
```

Answer (score 1):

`lubridate::today()` returns a character, same as `Sys.Date()`. But in the absence of a date in the first cell `data.frame()` will interprete this `NA` as a number. So use `as.character()` and outside the vector `as.Date()`.

```
d <- data.frame(a = as.Date(c(NA,as.character(lubridate::today()))),
                b = c(2,2))
d
```

returns:

```
 a           b
<date>       <dbl>
<NA>         2          
2022-08-16   2
```